# Creating unique id and counter for the instances of the same class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a small piece of software that lets you add controls in runtime.

What I've done is creating a derived class from the controls, and those include a static integer counter which is increased every time an instance of that class is constructed. This lets me create a naming convention so the names never repeat itself. For example I say

```
this.Name = "Label"+counter;
```

The problem comes when I want to store this in a sort of custom serialization. Lets say that I create 3 labels: *Label0, Label1, Label2* and then, I delete the *Label1*. Which would lead in having *Label0 and Label2*.

If I serialize the current state, and then I load that data to rebuild the state, the creation of labels would lead to have the counter as the value of 1, being the name of the last label *"Label2"*. This implies that if now I want to create another label, would be *"Label(counter+1)"*, that is, *"Label2"*, resulting in a duplicate.

My question is, which is the best way to create a counter that results in a naming convention as simple as this and skips duplicated names?

Comment: You should probably just save the ID when you serialize it...

Comment: Will you load serialized controls only when there are no existing controls (or equivalently, destroy all existing controls when you load the serialized controls)?  If not, the problem is a bit more complex because you have to also deal with collisions between the names of existing controls and the control(s) you load.

Comment: try this.Name = "Label"+GUID(), GUID is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize counter with other controls, then you can load exiting controls and also create new controls by using counter value.